# Can't access swarm : bzz://theswarm.eth/ from mist browser

Tags: mist, swarm

When accessing the URL in Mist, and after connecting my account, I get an empty white screen.
Running on OS X with the version 0.11.1 of Mist. 
Any idea where it could come from ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I thought mist did not have support for `bzz:` yet? Can you access through a regular browser using `http://localhost:8500/bzz:/theswarm.eth/` (where swarm HTTP listens when you are running a local node)